# Laravel - Method App\Http\Controllers\MsisdnController::export does not exist

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to export to Excel in Laravel 5.8 using

> "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"

but I got this error:

> Method App\Http\Controllers\MsisdnController::export does not exist.

Exports

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class MsisdnExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

MsisdnController

```
use App\Exports\MsisdnExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class MsisdnController extends Controller
{


    public function msisdnexport() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new MsisdnExport, 'msisdn.xlsx');
    }    
}
```

Sidebar Nav

```
<li><a href="{{ route('msisdnexport') }}">List of MSISDNs</a> </li>
```

route

```
Route::get('msisdnexport', 'MsisdnController@export')->name('msisdnexport');
```

View

```
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
            <a href="{{ route('msisdnexport') }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
        </div>

        @foreach($msisdns as $key => $msisdn)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $msisdn->phone }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

When I click on Excel Button, I expect it to export to Excel. But I got the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route definition:

```
Route::get('msisdnexport', 'MsisdnController@export');
```

references a function `export` that doesn't exist. Your function is named `msisdnexport` in your controller.